# Where can I buy a small piece of copper to use as a laptop GPU shim?

Tags: gpu, soldering

I was recently given am HP DV2000 laptop that has the nVidia GPU problem. I'm going to attempt reflowing the solder on it to see if I can get it working, and have seen many guides that mention after reflowing the solder putting in a copper shim instead of the thermal foam that's used between the heatsink and the chip.

I'd like to just grab that locally, although I've no idea where I could find a piece that's suitable. I'd need something around 1-1.5 mm thick, and a perhaps 2" x 3" so that I can cut it to size. The best guide I saw they had the shim extend out to where the laptop fan blew on a small bit of it.

I found [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003AU3BMG) on Amazon, but since I don't know the dimensions I don't know that it'd be appropriate. There are others listed on there, but I'd prefer to cut mine to size.

Any ideas? [Home Depot, Ace, Sears?]

Comment: Hobby shop.  They generally have brass sheet in various (small) sizes and thicknesses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call a roofing company and ask for a small piece of scrap.  They use sheet copper for very high-end, very expensive roofs.  (They last 300 years.)